# #define macro not in scope when i try to use IR library

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

My code keeps saying that that Button_8 and the rest of the #define macros are out of scope.

```
#include <IRLib.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define MY_PROTOCOL SONY
#define RIGHT_ARROW   0xfd50af //Move several clockwise
#define LEFT_ARROW    0xfd10ef //Move servo counterclockwise
#define SELECT_BUTTON 0xfd906f //Center the servo
#define UP_ARROW      0xfda05f //Increased number of degrees servo 
#define DOWN_ARROW    0xfdb04f //Decrease number of degrees servo moves
#define BUTTON_0 0xfd30cf  //Pushing buttons 0-9 moves to fixed  positions
#define BUTTON_1 0xfd08f7  // each 20 degrees greater
#define BUTTON_2 0xfd8877
#define BUTTON_3 0xfd48b7
#define BUTTON_4 0xfd28d7
#define BUTTON_5 0xfda857
#define BUTTON_6 0xfd6897
#define BUTTON_7 0xfd18e7
#define BUTTON_8 0xfd9867
#define BUTTON_9 0xfd58a7

IRrecv My_Receiver(11);//Receive on pin 11
IRdecode My_Decoder; 
long Previous;
Servo myservo2;
Servo myservo;  


void setup() 
{
myservo.attach(8); 
myservo2.attach(3);
My_Receiver.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() 
{

  if (My_Receiver.GetResults(&My_Decoder))
{
   My_Decoder.decode();
   if(My_Decoder.decode_type==MY_PROTOCOL) 
   {
       if(My_Decoder.value==0xFFFFFFFF)
       My_Decoder.value= Previous;
       if(My_Decoder.value == Button_9)
       {
       myservo.write(0);
       myservo2.write(180);
       }
     else if(My_Decoder.value == Button_8)
      {
         myservo.write(180);
          myservo2.write(180);
       }


    }
}
}
```

when i use a switch statement instead of the 4 and 5 if statement like so:

```
switch(My_Decoder.value) {
        case Button_8:   //do something; break;
```

it works, but i dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is case-sensitive. `Button_8` is different from `BUTTON_8`.